# How to pass a C++ string to Java JNI in a well defined thread-safe way?

Tags: java, c++, string, java-native-interface, thread-safety

There is a C++ function, which is called from Java code via JNI.
I want to pass the underlying c-string to the Java correctly, so I have done below arrangements:

```
// main.cpp
string global;

const char* data ()  // Called externally by JNI
{
  return (global = func_returning_string()).data();  // `.data()` = `.c_str()`
}
```

But in this case, the function `data()` is no longer thread-safe.
What is the best way to achieve the thread-safety while passing the string without causing any undefined behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to pass the underlying c-string to the Java correctly

How are you passing c++ string to java? You can't pass bare C++ pointer to Java, you should use JNI functions for that, ie.:

```
jstring jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, data());
```

and then pass `jstr` to Java, or pass in the form of a Java array. This function duplicates string so there is no problem with thread safety.

If you want to share memory region between Java and C++ then you might try with following JNI functions: `NewDirectByteBuffer`, `GetDirectBufferAddress`, `GetDirectBufferCapacity`.

Comment: Currently I am not using `jstring` etc. in my code to keep it independent of Java (since it's also used for iPhone). Though I can add it by segregation. Is there any other way, besides this?

Comment: I work with c++ code under android, we have a layer of code that glues java code with c++ engine - and this is using jni. other way - for getting data from c++? - you could also pass Java array to c++ code, and make c++ code fill it with string contents.

Comment: @iammilind `NewStringUTF` assumes that `data()` returns a pointer to a 0x00-terminated _modified UTF-8_ string. If it's not, maybe you can determine that all possible strings in your data are compatible.